# 16 -bit CLA instantiation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

DO I need anything else to make a 16bit CLA ??????

so far I instantiated 4 (4 bit CLA to make a 16 bit CLA)

but I think I am missing about the carry I just don't understand how to add it to what I have since the 8 bit CLA was just instantiating 2 (4 bit CLA) I don't understand why can't just instantiate 4 (4 bit CLA together to get 16 bit CLA). Can someone help me figure out how to complete the 16bit CLA?

```
//CLA16Top.sv

module CLA4Bit(ain, bin, cin, sum, cout);
timeunit 1ns/1ns;
input [3:0] ain,bin;
input cin;
    output logic [3:0] sum;
    output logic cout;

  logic [3:0] G,P,C;

// Carry propagate 
assign P = ain ^ bin;

//Carry generate
assign G = ain & bin;

// Calculating each stage of the carry out 
assign    C[0] = cin;
assign #4 C[1] = (G[0] | (C[0] & P[0]));
assign #6 C[2] = (G[1] | (G[0] & P[1]) | (C[0] & P[1] & P[0]));
assign #8 C[3] = (G[2] | (G[1] & P[2]) | (G[0] & P[1] & P[2]) | (C[0] & 
                  P[2] & P[1] & P[0]));

 assign sum = P ^ C;

assign #13 cout= (G[3] | (G[2]&P[3]) | (G[1]&P[2]&P[3]) | 
                  (G[0]&P[1]&P[2]&P[3]) | (C[0]&P[0]&P[1]&P[2]&P[3])); 

endmodule                                    


/*
   module CLA16Top;
  timeunit 1ns/1ns;
  parameter nBITS = 16;
  logic [nBITS - 1 : 0] ain, bin, sum;
  logic in;
  logic cout;

  logic c4, c8, c12, c16;

  assign cout = c16;

  // instantiating the 16 bit CLA
    
  CLA4Bit uut1(
    .ain(ain[3:0]),
    .bin(bin[3:0]),
    .cin(cin),
    .sum(sum[3:0]),
    .cout(c4)
    );

    CLA4Bit uut2(
    .ain(ain[7:4]),
    .bin(bin[7:4]),
    .cin(c4),
    .sum(sum[7:4]),
    .cout(c8)
    );

    CLA4Bit uut3(
    .ain(ain[11:8]),
    .bin(bin[11:8]),
    .cin(c8),
    .sum(sum[11:8]),
    .cout(c12)
     );

     CLA4Bit uut4(
    .ain(ain[15:12]),
    .bin(bin[15:12]),
    .cin(c12),
    .sum(sum[15:12]),
    .cout(c16)
    );
    

    // SIMULATE (CLA16Top)
    //
    test #(16) TB(.*);
    
    endmodule: CLA16Top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get compile errors in your `test` module.  Change:

```
  output in;
```

to:

```
  output cin;
```

Also, the double-quoted string must be on one line:

```
$display("For inputs: ain = %b, bin = %b, cin = %b :: Actual outputs: cout = %1b, sum = %b :: Expected outputs: cout = %1b, sum = %b", ain, bin, cin, cout,
```

`test_count` could be too big to fit into an `int` variable.  Use `real` and `%g`:

```
  real test_count;

    $display("***Congratulations, No errors found after %g tests***", test_count);
```

After those changes, the code compiles and runs for me.  It took about **2 hours** before the nested loops completed, and only the final message displays:

```
***Congratulations, No errors found after 8.58993e+09 tests***
```

This indicates that the adder works properly.

If you want to see more intermediate results, add more displays in the loops.

---

Note: The `test` module code was removed from the Question after I posted this Answer.